# Google Maps Api v3 - Refresh Markerclusterer after Domready

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I instanciate a MarkerClusterer like this :

```
markerClusterer = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, {
    maxZoom: zoom,
    gridSize: size,
    styles: styles
});
```

After loading, I add some marker to the map.
How can I refresh my clusterer so what it takes the new marker into consideration ?

Now, if I zoom out, the new marker is not clustered.

In advance, thank you !

Note : I don't use MasterClusterer Plus

Comment: I know, but I have to wait 8 hours because I have less than 10 reputation :). I'll do it tonight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, I didn't use the markerClusterer.addMarker function...
It works fine now !

-> http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/docs/reference.html